# cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have  login page in my application  in that  I have save my designation ID in Cookies 
like

```
Response.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DesignationID"].ToString();
```

and after  User  Login  In another page  I want   to retrive  that  cookie  value so  I have written code like

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value = 2))
```

but it show error  like cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' c# and  that red dotted line is  under 2 ...so please give  me   some hint...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should probably have:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value) == 2)
```

So a misplaced bracket, and an assignment rather than equality operator. Or just compare to string:

```
if (Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value == "2")
```

Comment: +1 for the comparing to a string method. The first could throw an exception if `DesignationID` was not an integer for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OK, I kind of misread this. Here's a better version:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value) == 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That won't even compile will it?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an answer get upvoted so much, then downvoted so quickly.

Comment: that's because the answer is incorrect.. expecially the `=="2"` no need for the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value) == 2)
 {
 //Everything else here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value) == 2)
```

or you can use to prevent more memory spacing using Int32

```
if (int.Parse(Request.Cookies["DesignationID"].Value) == 2)
```